# Two headers when using nested Stacknavigators

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

In my react native app I am using TabNavigator inside a StackNavigator as so:

```
const AppTabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: Tab1,
    Create: Tab2,
    Search: Tab3,
    Ask: Tab4
  }
);

const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Tabs: AppTabs,
    Screen2: SecondScreen,
    Screen3: ThirdScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Tabs"
  }
);
```

This works fine but when I try to use another StackNavigator for the Search Tab, two headers are displayed and the only solution I have found is to hide the nested StackNavigator's header with `headerMode: "none"`:

```
const SearchStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Search: SearchScreen,
    Post: PostScreen,
  },
  {
    headerMode: "none",
    navigationOptions: {
      headerShown: false
    },
    initialRouteName: "Search"
  }
);
```

However, this functionality is not best for my app. I need the outside StackNavigator's header to be hidden instead when the Search tab is in focus so the user can still go back and forth between screens in the nested Search Stack. Can someone advise me what I should do to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using react-navigation in the wrong way, you should not make separate stack navigator for SearchStack, instead you should add SearchStack's screens in AppStack only.

```js
const AppTabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: Tab1,
    Create: Tab2,
    Search: Tab3,
    Ask: Tab4
  }
);

const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Tabs: AppTabs,
    Post: PostScreen,
    Screen2: SecondScreen,
    Screen3: ThirdScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Tabs"
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `AppStack` navigator to the following:

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Tabs: AppTabs,
    Screen2: SecondScreen,
    Screen3: ThirdScreen,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      const currentRoute = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
      const {routeName} = currentRoute;

      let tabBarVisible = true;

      if (routeName === 'Search') {
        tabBarVisible = false;
      }

      return {
        headerShown: tabBarVisible,
      };
    },
    initialRouteName: 'Tabs',
  },
);
```

If the app is rendering the `Search` route, the `headerShown` property of your top most `StackNavigator` (`AppStack`) will be set to false. Meaning the app will not show the `AppStack` header when rendering the `Search` route.

The `SearchStack` navigator can be defined simply like this:

```
const SearchStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Search: SearchScreen,
    Post: PostScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Search',
  },
);
```

Comment: This method also works, the chosen answer just showed a simpler way for my case

Answer (score 1):

> Simply use below code in the page you want to hide the header

```
export default class SearchScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    }
}
```

Comment: This hides the `SearchScreen` header, but that is not what he is asking.